# My Label sets up any text but I can't see it on screen but it can be seen from console

Tags: java, javafx, label

I was working with the label.But when I used the label.settext("Something"). It was working in the background that means it sets the string but it doesn't show it on the screen. You can ask me how you know this? I checked it on my console by using System.out.println(label.gettext()). It gives the correct output. But the level did not show "Something".

```
serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) -> {
        try{
            System.out.println("Your selected text for label : "+objectname);
                objectname="Nothing";
            label2.setText(objectname);
            System.out.println("Label gettext : "+label2.getText());    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And it gives ->
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = EventThread COM5

Comment: Your example appears to satisfy the minimal constraint, but not the complete constraint. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You help us more, we can try to help you *faster*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every change to any JavaFX `Node` **must be** invoked in FX application thread. Provided exception explains this. I assume that `SerialPortEvent` is invoked in  separate thread, that is why you get an exception. To fix that set `Label`text in `Platform.runLater()`.

CODE:

```
serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("Your selected text for label : " + objectname);
        objectname = "Nothing";
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            label2.setText(objectname);
        });
        System.out.println("Label gettext : " + label2.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, This works for me:
As I was invoking SerialPortEvent in a separate thread, so it required to use Platform.runLater(() -> { });
Right code is given below:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        if(objectname!= null){
                            System.out.println("Previousobject : "+previousobject);
                        label2.setText(previousobject);
                        }
                    });
```